Is it possible to block the user when trying to login from outside organisation network with aws waf
I want to restrict the access to particular user when logged in from outside the organization network it should be blocked but within organization i want that user need to have the access within the organization. How can i achieve this setup with aws waf. I read some document it can be done with lambda. Any insights.

What is the user connecting to -- your own application running on an Amazon EC2 instance, or the AWS management console?
